# Delphi Word automation - print merged document

Tags: delphi, printing, ms-word, mailmerge

My D5 application can currently mail merge multiple members data to a Word document using:

```
wrdapp := CreateOleObjct(word.application);
wrdDoc := wrdApp.Document.Open(TemplateLocation);
wrdMailMerge := wrdDoc.MailMerge;
populateMailMergeDateFile;
wrdMailMerge.execute;
```

and then

```
wrdDoc.Saved := False;
wrdDoc.Close(False);
wrdApp.Visible := True;
```

I would like to offer the option of passing the merged document straight to the printer. However I cannot find the code which allows this to happen

```
wrdDoc.PrintOut;
wrdDoc.Saved := False;
wrdDoc.Close(False);
```

Prints out the template document with no merged data.

```
wrdDoc.Saved := False;
wrdDoc.Close(False);
wrdDoc.PrintOut;
```

Displays a variant object error.

```
wrdMailMerge.PrintOut;
```

Displays an automation errors.

I've tried using True instead of False as well. Can anybody advise me as to how to print the merged document correctly?

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my mailmerge code, I set MailMerge.Destination to wdSendToNewDocument before executing the merge, then afterwards I call WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Printout.

Comment: yeah I had that MailMerge.Destination := wdSendToNewDocument before executing the merge. However it didn't make a difference to displaying the merge when it was removed. When I try printing the active document as you suggest it gives me "RPC server is unavaible"

Comment: *edit* 
I was saving and closing the document before printing. It works! thanks frogb :) Can anyone tell me the significance of True and False in the save and close statements?

Comment: @notidaho: You shouldn't use False or True in the Close method, you have to specify a wdSaveOption, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238160%28office.12%29.aspx